# Como criar rotas por usuário .NetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

Eu preciso criar um site de vendas e cada usuário terá seu próprio "site" seria algo do tipo meusistema.com.br/username
Qual é a melhor forma de fazer isso usando .NetCore?